# slow query that runs instantaneously from mysql-client

Tags: mysql

I have a slow query logged in /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log, run from php using PDO, and when I copy-paste it in mysql-client, I get the answer instantaneously, even after restarting mysql. How do you explain that?

Here is the query:

> SELECT many_fields FROM some_table u WHERE (u.created_at >= '2011-11-01' AND u.created_at <= '2012-02-01' AND u.valid IS TRUE AND u.test IS FALSE);

Here is the explain of the query:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 86460 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
```

Here is the output of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST when running the php script:

```
+-----+---------+-----------+-----------------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| Id  | User    | Host      | db                    | Command | Time | State | Info                  |
+-----+---------+-----------+-----------------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
|   9 |some_user| localhost | some_db               | Query   |    0 | NULL  | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST |
| 187 |some_user| localhost | some_db               | Sleep   |    6 |       | NULL                  |
+-----+---------+-----------+-----------------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Are you logging queries not using indexes?

Comment: yes, I'll add an `EXPLAIN` in a few seconds. When I run the task that runs this query, I see the query in `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in your reply to my comment, you are logging queries that don't use indexes.  This query is not using an index, so it gets logged with the slow queries.  Queries that are logged because they don't use an index ignore the minimum execution time when being logged.

Edit: The `Time` column in `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` shows the time it has been in its current state, which is usually set to `Sleep` when a query finishes so that time is not reliable for timing queries.  To get a more reliable timing of the query, you'd need to use profiling or some other way of benchmarking that works more directly with the query.

Comment: I was going to. The output of `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` disagrees with you

Comment: @greg0ire How?  The `EXPLAIN` shows that it isn't using an index.

Comment: The time column shows '6', and I can wait longer, but just to be sure, I'm going to disable the "not using index" logging

Comment: @greg0ire The time column is how long it has been in that state.  In this case, it has been sleeping for 6 seconds.  That has nothing to do with the previous query.  If you check the processes list again in a few seconds, that number should increase assuming that nothing happens with that thread.

Comment: It looks like you're right: the slow log does not show the query. Please edit your answer, it looks like I can't upvote you otherwise.

Comment: Plus, the php process is taking all the CPU, so this must be a hydration problem, not a mysql problem. Thanks!